# Common emitter amplifier with load resistance

Tags: amplifier

I can't seem to grasp how to calculate the values for a common emitter with a load resistance, to cascade an amplifier in multiple stages.

I'm trying to obtain an 8.5-9Vptp output from a 12V supply on a 5520 ohm load resistance. Not trying to achieve much gain since it can be achieved in earlier stages so ~5.
I took:

Ic = 10mA

DC emitter 0.5V about ground

Vce min = 1V

This is what I've got

[image]

However, once I actually built the circuit on a breadboard the output ended up being 4Vptp, half of what I actually had in the simulation.
What am I doing wrong?

Complete circuit:
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93433/discussion-on-question-by-matt-common-emitter-amplifier-with-load-resistance).  Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).

Comment: Look at the date of this question!

Answer (score 0):

For temperature stability, and the wide output Volts PeakPeak, I'd consider this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkc9K3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Maybe add some description for why D1 and why R3 would need to be resized ?

Comment: 100 ohms for R2 and R3 are awful low resistance.  why would you want so much current flowing down that branch and also have your input impedance so low?

Comment: his resistor values are different, between the 2 versions of the 5X amplifier; thus the OP can replace the 100 ohms with what he finds will perform correct biasing and gain-setting.